# Symfony 2: Collect controllers annotations on KernelRequest

Tags: symfony, routes, containers

Actually I want to store all the routing in the database. I wrote custom annotation class called `VendorRoute` I can read this annotation for a single controller, but does anybody know how to read this annotation for all controllers in application?

Comment: Dynamic Router may help,

http://symfony.com/doc/master/cmf/bundles/routing.html#dynamic-router

Comment: It's not the thing I need. Actually i need described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved my problem. In Sf2 it's impossible out of the box. Check out my implementation https://github.com/Codeforges/CayenneCoreBundle/blob/master/Annotations/Driver/CayenneRouteDriver.php#L83